# Semicircle - Sketching Points

Tags: linear-algebra, radicals

I am having problems understanding how to sketch/solve  $x = \sqrt{1 - (y-1)^2}$.

Please, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}$

$x^2=1-(y-1)^2$

$(y-1)^2=1-x^2$

$(y-1)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}+1$

---

Note that since the original equation yields $x\geq0$, only the right side of the graph below is relevant:

[image]

Comment: Thnaks for the help

Comment: @foo: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides and simplify to get the equation of a well known curve.
Then, note that $x \gt 0$

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: @foo How about if you would follow the advice given by tpb? Square both sides of the equation and see what you get, then comment about what you get, not just "please elaborate".

Comment: foo as @5xum stated, update your question with what you did, it'll help to help you better

Comment: I am fairly new to this subject, and i was not able to complete it correctly, i have the answers, but needed help understanding the methodology, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=r^{2}$$

is the equation of a circle with radius $r$ and center at $(a,b)$. In your case, x is restricted to

$$0\leq x \leq a+r$$